# Не удается подключиться к Dante Server

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, proxy, socks5

Решил сделать socks5 серевер с помощью Amazon AWS. На сервере Ubuntu 18.04. Установил dante-server, подправил конфиг и запустил демон на 1080 порту. Все работает исправно, в логах все чисто. Тем не менее подключиться к моему серверу через 1080 порт не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой. Вторую ночь не сплю. Быть может нужно открыть 1080 порт с помощью iptables?

danted.conf:

```
logoutput: /var/log/danted.log

internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0

socksmethod: username
user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0/0 to: 0/0
        log: error
}

socks pass {
        from: 0/0 to: 0/0
        lo
}
```

Вот что выдает netstat -tulpn:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3035/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20420/sshd          
tcp        0      0 172.31.46.156:1080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25655/danted        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      20420/sshd          
tcp6       0      0 fe80::828:deff:fea:1080 :::*                    LISTEN      25655/danted        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           3035/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 172.31.46.156:68        0.0.0.0:*                           3019/systemd-networ
```

danted.log:

```
Jun  7 22:33:40 (1559946820.969234) danted[25484]: info: Dante/server[1/1] v1.4.2 running
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.965354) danted[25484]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.967712) danted[25491]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.967936) danted[25492]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.973444) danted[25493]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.973530) danted[25494]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.973847) danted[25495]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974040) danted[25496]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974209) danted[25497]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974390) danted[25498]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974564) danted[25499]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974747) danted[25500]: info: sigterm(): exiting on signal 15
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974918) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25491 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974933) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25492 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974944) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25493 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974955) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25494 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974965) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25495 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974974) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25496 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974985) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25497 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.974995) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25498 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.975005) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25499 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.975016) danted[25484]: warning: closechild(): failed to notify request-child 25500 it should exit normally: Broken pipe
Jun  7 22:38:18 (1559947098.975103) danted[25484]: alert: mother[1/1]: shutting down
Jun  7 22:38:19 (1559947099.024827) danted[25655]: info: Dante/server[1/1] v1.4.2 running
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему открытием порта. Я пытался его открыть и до этого с помощью ufw и iptables, но не получалось. Оказалось, что открывать порты у ec2 сервера нужно через Amazon Console на сайте Amazon AWS.